# How to calculate $\frac{d}{d\lambda}(f(\lambda x,\lambda y))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I'm solving a problem from my differential equation's course, and for certain prove I need to calculate
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}g(\lambda),$$
being $g(\lambda)=f(\lambda x,\lambda y)$. A classmate sent me a photo of his solution and I noticed he stated that
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}(f(\lambda x,\lambda y))=\frac{\partial f(\lambda x,\lambda y)}{\partial \lambda x}\cdot\frac{\partial\lambda x}{\partial\lambda} + \frac{\partial f(\lambda x,\lambda y)}{\partial \lambda y}\cdot\frac{\partial\lambda y}{\partial\lambda}.$$
Is this true? If so, why is it true? I'm having trouble figuring out how this derivative works. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your classmate's notation is strange to me, but the solution is correct. This is simply a consequence of the [multivariate chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case).

Comment: Or, if you prefer, we could work directly from the definition of what it means for a function on two variables to be "differentiable" (which is not *only* that the partial derivatives exist)

Comment: Alternatively, you could figure this out using the definition of the "directional derivative" of the function $f$ at a certain point. Note that the result on the right can be written as a dot-product between the gradient and another vector

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks!